# Istio Envoy Proxy breaks Thrift Service - Hive Metastore

Tags: kubernetes, hive, istio, envoyproxy, hive-metastore

I am trying to run the thrift server (Hive metastore aka HMS) behind the istio Envoy proxy. The HMS works well when I run the service in a namespace with istio-injection disabled. But when i try the service in the istio enabled namespace, the connection fails. When i check the logs from the proxy container,I see the below logs

`"- - HTTP/1.1" 400 DPE http1.codec_error - "-" 0 11 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 192.168.60.47:9083 192.168.65.190:34996 - -`

The error message suggests that the Istio Envoy proxy is unable to decode the HTTP request from the upstream server. Is thrift service not support by Envoy proxy?

Note: With `sidecar.istio.io/inject: false` it works fine.